# How to Implement HP and auto restart the game after game over

Tags: python-3.x

So I am making a game and I am very new to python as a coding language and I am not currently taking a class for it I am self learning. I am making a text based game to start of with. I want to implement HP as a factor and give an option to restart the game when you get a game over. Here is the code I have so far.

```
print("Welcome to the journey to Camelot. This game is case sensitive, type the answers exactly as shown!")
print("\nYou wake up and decide today you are going to become a knight of the round table. You are a skinny average joe"
  " but, that does not bother you. You hunker up, get dressed, and decide what to bring with you. Do you bring a"
  " 'Bow' or a 'Sword?'")
SwordBow = input('>')
if SwordBow == "Bow":
     print("\nYou pick up your trusty bow and get ready to leave. You walk outside and notice it is raining. "
      "This makes you lose some of your determination for this trip. Do you 'Go Home' or 'Continue Onward'")
     GoHomeContinueOnward = input('>')
     if GoHomeContinueOnward == "Go Home":
          print("\nYou go home and go to the sleep, game over.")
          ##Instance of a game over
     elif GoHomeContinueOnward == "Continue Onward":
          print("\nFiller")
elif SwordBow == "Sword":
     print("\nYou pick up your sturdy sword and prepare to leave. You notice it is raining. This makes you realize your"
      " sword could rust. Do you 'Stick it under your shirt' or 'Eh keep it sheathed'?")
     StickitunderyourshirtEhkeepitsheathed = input('>')
     if StickitunderyourshirtEhkeepitsheathed == "Stick it under your shirt":
          print("\nFiller")
          print("\nYou have lost 10HP") 
          ##Here is one of the reasons I want to implement HP
     elif StickitunderyourshirtEhkeepitsheathed == "Eh keep it sheathed":
     print("\nFiller")
```

I want you to be able to lose HP and if you get too low get a game over such as, if 
HP > 0:
     print("Game Over")
I am sorry for bothering your time with these simple questions but as I said I am very new to python and this is the first full thing I have tried to code. In the end I want it to just be a choice based flowchart style text adventure. I also want the feature to restart after getting a game over. Thank you in advance for any help and I only ask so I know how in the future to avoid clutter, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the site :)

The first thing I notice is the length of your variable names. `StickitunderyourshirtEhkeepitsheathed` is really long and hard to read; rename it to something short yet descriptive, maybe `weapon_action`, and use an underscore to separate the words.

To implement `hp`, simply add a variable at the beginning of the script called `hp` and give it a default value; e.g. `hp = 100`. Then, after `print("\nYou have lost 10HP")` write `hp -= 10` or `hp = hp - 10` (they mean the same) to subtract 10 from `hp`.

You should check out some tutorials on how to write functions since that's what you'll need to easily re-run your game. At the moment, your script will be executed from top to bottom and there's no easy way of returning to the beginning. If you put everything in a function, e.g. `def main():`, `def game():` or whatever you want to call it, you can simply call that function every time you want to re-run it.

Comment: Ok thank you for the response. I did at one point have def game(): at the beginning at one point but it was creating a weird bug with my first print command but I will have to try that out again. I appreciate the response as I am in Highschool all honors classing while trying to teach myself to code, the quick answers help :)

Comment: @ZacharyArthur Cool, you're welcome. I'm also a self-learner and enjoy all the free homework I get to do on SO - never thought I'd say that :O Anyway, putting your code in functions is the way to go. As soon as your game grows in size and complexity, it'll become confusing without some sort of encapsulation. When the project grows even more, you'll probably want to put the functions in classes and then you're doing object oriented programming :)